# The mesh is twisted by rigging

Tags: mesh, rigging

I'm a begginer with Blender : this is the 4th rime I'm doing something on this software! I've been modeling this mesh. Everything went okay, I did a simple rigging. And this happen... It seems like all points of the mesh are following the rig and I can't understand why. I tried to remove doubles on the original mesh, I tried to remove weight paint...

[image]

What I can't understand is I did a similar 3D model earlier and everything went fine with Automatic Weights.

[image]

Any suggestion ? Can you help me, please ? Thank you by advance !

EDIT : I could upload the file [here](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51922&fbclid=IwAR2nAKciq1YidJ9Zfd0ED_9-FFMdz6XeHMDNP7Z0CHLaYIrhgn06rVyZrLE) I did another 3D model and I have the same problem... I can't understand what I'm doing wrong !

Comment: Was your mesh a T pose, and was your armature in Rest pose when you parented? Maybe share your file... https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Check that you have applied scale/rotation etc to both the mesh and the armature, and then try to generate the weights again.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answers. I still have the problem, and I can't share the file because the upload fails everytime. What do you exactly mean by "apply scale/rotation" ? Sorry, not very gifted with Blender haha !